# How to add curved corners for a pentagon using html5 canvas?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I wanted to create a pentagon with html5 and canvas, but I am stuck in adding curved corners for the pentagon.

```js
$(function(){
   var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
   var cxt=canvas.getContext("2d");
    // hexagon
    var numberOfSides = 5,
        size = 100,
        Xcenter = 150,
        Ycenter = 150,
        step  = 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides,//Precalculate step value
        shift = (Math.PI / 180.0) * -18;//Quick fix ;)

    cxt.beginPath();
    //cxt.moveTo (Xcenter +  size * Math.cos(0), Ycenter +  size *  Math.sin(0));          

    for (var i = 0; i <= numberOfSides;i++) {
     var curStep = i * step + shift;
        cxt.lineTo (Xcenter + size * Math.cos(curStep), Ycenter + size * Math.sin(curStep));
    }

    cxt.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    cxt.lineWidth = 1;
    cxt.stroke();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width=650 height=500></canvas>
```

Comment: But you already created a pentagon. What is your question?

Comment: i would like to create a pentagon with curved edges. right now it is sharp

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `ctx.arc()` for drawing curved edges. See this [simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/j8593dtf/4/).

```js
function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (canvas.getContext){
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(75,75,20,0,2,false); 
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
 <body onload="draw();">
   <canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

Draw angles and add they in your pentagon.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mr.JS, If the petagon is stable with no animation, we can find the draw arc with coordinates, but if there is an animation then arc is breaking the pentagon.